# PHP: are switch-case statements with strings inefficient?

Tags: php, performance, string, switch-statement

In my PHP layer I'm receiving error codes as strings ("NOT_FOUND", "EXPIRED", etc). It's a small list of possible strings, perhaps a dozen.

What's the most efficient way of dealing with these? Using switch-case against string constants stored in a class, or should I parse them to numbers (or something) first? Or is PHP smart enough so it doesn't really matter?

Comment: **Don't worry about it!** You're talking about differences of a handful of processor cycles at best, nothing you will ever notice. Write it the way that's most readable and maintainable.

Comment: @deceze  Yeah you are probably right but using plain strings is a bad way to go if you ever have to change a value... using the static class constants a simple refractor should do it (hopefully ;)

Comment: @Michael That goes with what I wrote about maintainability. *Performance* shouldn't be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using constants? Let's say you have a class `Error` and define all error codes there like this:

```
class Error {
   const NOT_FOUND = 0;
   const EXPIRED = 1;
   // and so forth
}
```

And then you can use them in your code by accessing them like `Error::NOT_FOUND` and a switch statement wouldn't need to compare strings but has plain ints without downgrading readability.

Comment: Yeah, that was my other option. But since the codes are strings, not numbers, and PHP anyway can handle strings in switch-case statements or as indices to arrays, is there a point mapping them to integers like that?

Comment: @PapaFreud No, of course you can choose what ever you want the constants to be.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do with the strings. Do you want to output error messages? Then instead of a case statement you could use a lookup table like this:

```
$messages = array(
  'NOT_FOUND' => 'The file was not found',
  'EXPIRED' => 'The cookie expired'
  // ETC
);
echo empty($messages[$error]) ? "Unknown error" : $messages[$error];
```

With PHP 5.3 you could also store code in the array to handle the error situations:

```
$handlers = array(
  'NOT_FOUND' => function() { /* Error handling code here */ },
  'EXPIRED' => function() { /* Other error handling code */ }
 );
 if(!empty($handlers[$error])) { 
   $handler = $handlers[$error];
   $handler();
 }
 else {
   echo "Could not handle error!"; die();
 }
```

With a technique like this you avoid case statements that go over several pages.

With PHP < 5.3 you might look into `call_user_func` for dynamic dispatching of error handling functions.

Answer (score 0):

Strings can't be recognised as class constants. But the answer on your question is that it doesnt really matter if you do it like this:

```
switch (className::{$errorCode}) { // $errorCode == name of the constant, like NOT_FOUND
// Cases here.
}
```